(Beginner)My AI(U-net) isnt training/testing properly
I'm new to AI and Python, so I've been trying to use U-net to create an AI that can identify and segment cracks. My results are like this:
Epoch 5/25
20/20 [==============================] - 42s 2s/step - loss: -12.7775 - accuracy: 0.0591 - dice_coef: 1.3771 - iou: 2.9680 - val_loss: 0.9940 - val_accuracy: 0.4198 - val_dice_coef: 0.9033 - val_iou: 0.9226

Strangely, with each epoch, the loss and accuracy keep decreasing, while the dice coefficient and IOU keep increasing.
Epochs results
I'm gonna share what i tried:
Images for training:
Mask for exampleMain Image
This following code shows how i'm reading and treating my images=
#Xtrain = main images get resized to 128x128
#Ytrain = Mask images gets turned to gray, resized to 128x128 and gets a new channel 1
def readimg(name_image, list_images):
    path_image = os.path.join('crack_dataset/img', name_image)
    if os.path.exists(path_image):
        image = cv2.imread(path_image)
        image = cv2.resize(image,(128,128))
        Xtrain.append(image)

def leimg_mask(name_image, list_images):
    path_image = os.path.join('crack_dataset/labelcol', nome_imagem)
    if os.path.exists(path_image):
        image = cv2.imread(path_image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image = cv2.resize(image,(128,128))
        mask_array = image[:, :, np.newaxis]
        Ytrain.append(mask_array)

Then, Xtrain and Ytrain turns to a NumPy ndarray. And Xtrain gets normalized
Xtrain = np.array(Xtrain)
Ytrain = np.array(Ytrain)
Xtrain = Xtrain / 255.0

creating Image data generator. Datagen for train and datagen_test for test
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=15,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    brightness_range=[0.7, 1.3],
    fill_mode="nearest"
)
datagen_test = ImageDataGenerator()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xtrain, Ytrain, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

Model below
Model part 1
Model part 2
train_generator = datagen.flow(
    X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, shuffle=True
)

val_generator = datagen_test.flow(
    X_test, y_test, batch_size=16, shuffle=False
)
many_steps = len(train_generator)
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=many_steps, epochs=25, validation_data=val_generator)

Help please :(

Please don't post images of code/results, see the reasons.

Generally, a negative cross entropy loss should not happen. Are your mask images properly scaled in [0, 1] values?

yes, they are normalized and all values in the array values go from [0 to 1]

Take a look at this answer, especially the part "How can the loss be negative?". I know I already asked this, but for binary CE to be negative, the labels has to be wrong somehow. Otherwise it is impossible for bce to be negative. Also please note that ImageDataGenerator is deptrecated.

Hi, I have reviewed your code, and as you mentioned that the loss and
accuracy are not improving, I would recommend performing hyperparameter
tuning using Keras Tuner. This could help improve the results of both loss
and accuracy.
